# Download and use of target dataset with Vuforia

Tags: swift, xcode, vuforia

I'm downloading a specific targets.xml file and I want to access this file to use with the Vuforia SDK. The file is downloaded to the Documents Directory of the app as follow:

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
    }
    else{
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
```

Now I want to access this file to use with Vuforia. I know this should be done by using STORAGE_ABSOLUTE in the load function.

```
// Load the data set from the app's resources location
if (!dataSet->load([dataFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], Vuforia::
            STORAGE_ABSOLUTE)) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to load data set");
            objectTracker->destroyDataSet(dataSet);
            dataSet = NULL;
            ret = NO;
} else {
            // Activate the data set
            if (objectTracker->activateDataSet(dataSet)) {
                NSLog(@"INFO: successfully activated data set");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to activate data set");
                ret = NO;
            }
        }
```

But I get the error beneath, I named the xml file, 'targets'. Maybe you guys know something I forgot?

```
2017-01-31 20:12:39.262178 VidPlayback[243:5487] ERROR/AR(243) 
2017-01-32 20:12:39: Failed to load dataset 'targets.xml'.
2017-01-31 20:12:39.262191 VidPlayback[243:5487] ERROR: failed to load data set
```

**Edit: fixed it!**

Used this link: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/remote-dataset-ios-sdk

Change the default code in the loadAndActivateImageTrackerDataSet function:

```
if (!dataSet->load([dataFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], Vuforia::
            STORAGE_ABSOLUTE))
```

with this:

```
NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), dataFile];

// Load the data set from the app's resources location
if (!dataSet->load([fullPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], Vuforia::STORAGE_ABSOLUTE)){
```

Comment: I know this sounds trivial, but did you try to print out the variable containing the exact path you are trying to load, and make sure the file is actually there?

Comment: The file is actually there, but I fixed it! I will edit my question.

Comment: @KNV Did you find the solution as I am not able ti load xml file from document directory

Comment: Check my edit...